# Height auto removes background color

Tags: html, css

I created a div that takes information text from a Javascript array and displays it on the screen like this "ca_explanation.innerHTML = q.explanation;". I wanted to make it responsive so I added "height:auto" and "padding:1%" to it so that even if it has large amounts of text it can still look good. But when I add the "height auto", the background color disappears. I took my code and put it in CodePen and the background color is there and working. I tried doing "*Ctrl + F5" but that didn't work. Anyone got any ideas on what could be causing this bug? Here is my code

ScreenShot of my problem
https://gyazo.com/93e9de154ea6e2b726b7a1e77022a67d

```css
.correct-div {
  width: 18%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 49.5%;
  right: 4%;
  float: right;
  /*display: none;*/
  padding:1%;
  background-color: #FBDF7E;
  line-height: 1.4;
}
```

```html
<div class="correct-div" id="correct-div">
    <p style="color:#32575E;font-weight:500;" id="ca-explaination">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: when i put it in a jsfiddle the background color works fine aswell, can you show us what you get? with a screenshot.

Comment: it’s because of the float

Comment: @raviramani can you explain why it's the float causing this problem?

Comment: your div's height totally depends on its container. Note, check `position` property

Comment: https://www.webrexstudio.com/use-of-clearfix-class/

Comment: I updated the code @RamondeVries

Comment: when you are floating any element then it’s behave like absolute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible your CSS is in conflict with something else you've written. Could you post a screenshot of your result along with the Chrome code inspector?

Comment: I updated my code and how do I do the code inspector?

Comment: Right click on the page element your are trying to look at (the div) and click **Inspect**. Alternatively you could press **CTRL+SHIFT+I**.

Comment: Ahh I found the problem, by checking the inspector, I found that something was conflicting with it. Thank you

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help.